# Error parsing XML - not well formed (invalid token)

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite

I have already checked the other XML files for errors, however this is the file that the error message is saying the error is in.  There is also a message that pops up whenever I try to run the app that says, "Files under the build folder are generated and should not be edited".

```
package com.example.drive.drivercorder;

import android.content.ContentValues; 

import android.content.Context;

import android.database.Cursor;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import android.util.Log;



public class DBAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;

    public static final String KEY_DRIVETIME = "Drive Time";
    public static final String KEY_NIGHTORDAY = "Time of Day";



    public static final int COL_DRIVETIME = 1;
    public static final int COL_NIGHTORDAY = 2;



    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_DRIVETIME, KEY_NIGHTORDAY, };


    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDb";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "mainTable";

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;   

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = 
            "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE 
            + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "

            + KEY_DRIVETIME + " integer not null, "
            + KEY_NIGHTORDAY + " text not null "



            + ");";


    private final Context context;

    private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;



    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
        myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }


    public DBAdapter open() {
        db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }


    public void close() {
        myDBHelper.close();
    }


    public long insertRow(int drivetime, String nightorday) {

        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_DRIVETIME, Drive Time);
        initialValues.put(KEY_NIGHTORDAY, Time of Day);



        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    public boolean deleteRow(long rowId) {
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
    }

    public void deleteAll() {
        Cursor c = getAllRows();
        long rowId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                deleteRow(c.getLong((int) rowId));              
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
    }


    public Cursor getAllRows() {
        String where = null;
        Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                            where, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }


    public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
        Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                        where, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }


    public boolean updateRow(long rowId, String drivetime, String nightorday) {
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;

        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        newValues.put(KEY_DRIVETIME, Drive Time);
        newValues.put(KEY_NIGHTORDAY, Time of Day);

        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
    }


    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
            _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);           
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version " + oldVersion
                    + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data!");

            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);


            onCreate(_db);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you post your DBAdapter?  You should be posting the LogCat output so more information about the error exists.  Judging by the "files under the build folder" comment, I'm guessing you accidentally edited one of the xml files inside the build folder.

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run 
  Error Code:
   1
  Output:
   /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/DriveRcorder/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/layout/dbadapter.java:2: error: Error parsing XML: syntax error

Comment: that is the error message in the run tab.

Comment: Do you have a java file in your layout directory?  Because that shouldn't be there.

Comment: where should I move the .java file to then?

Answer (score 0):

> There is also a message that pops up whenever I try to run the app that says, "Files under the build folder are generated and should not be edited".

I think you are changing the .class file in debug/DDMS mode or something like that. Please check and make sure to edit your .java file instead.

Posting your relevant logcat messages and also the XML file in question might help understand the problem.